# In android how do you search the internet and return the results in an activity?

Tags: java, android, search, webview

I want the user to input their search query into a search widget and then have the search results displayed to them and then when they click on a url that they want, I need to be able to save that url for use in other parts of my application.

Is this possible, and if not what are some of the restrictions preventing this?

---

EDIT -- I figured I'd add the code for my activity that has the webview.

```
public class State extends Activity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final boolean customTitleSupport = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.state);

        if( customTitleSupport ){
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title );
        }

        final TextView myTitleText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_title);
        if( myTitleText != null ){
            myTitleText.setText(R.string.app_name);
        }

        WebView stateBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.state_search);
        stateBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use something called WebViewClient

```
public class WebViewTestActivity extends Activity implements
        View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btn = null;
    WebView myWebView =null;
    EditText et =null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
// WebViewClient in use.
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                et.setText(url);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View source) {
        if (btn.getText().equals("Go!")) {
            myWebView.loadUrl(et.getText().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

`

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how that would work into the program.  Can you give an example?

Comment: `       WebView stateBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.state_search);
        stateBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");`
you can say
`stateBrowser.getOriginalUrl();`

Comment: so after the user inputs their search query into google and they select the link they are interested in (opening up that new link in a website) I can say stateBrowser.getOriginalUrl(); and that will grab the URL of the new site that they went to?

Comment: i;ve edited my answer to include a sample program.. you can use that as a reference point.